# I have a set of USB-classed barcode scanner and microcontroller board, how do I process the data?

Tags: microcontroller, data, processing, barcode

Questions:

1. Is the signal already readable for the microcontroller if I have both the scanner and the board match headed with USB?
2. I know that the scanner was programmed to output whatever the bar code means **followed by an "enter" stroke**, is this causing me unable to store it directly into a variable when I write the control program? If so, do I have to & how to eliminate that "enter" keystroke? Something to do with reformatting like demarcating them?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry about that, my main concern was assumming that I have successfully received the data from the scanner, and having known that the output of the scanner upon each scan will be the bar code number that ends with an enter stroke (I have tested the scanner in the excel doc), so that leads me wondering is it a problem if I need to process these bar code numbers later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably confusing a few concepts if worrying about trailing enter / carriage return characters seems to be an immediate concern. Likely the larger problems are:

- Most small / cheap / easy-to-use microcontrollers that have a USB interface only operate as a USB device the same as your USB scanner would. They would normally both be connected to a USB host such as a PC, so you can't connect them to each other.
- Implementing a complete USB host that you could connect the scanner to is quite complex so normally the quickest and easiest way there would be to use something like Linux that already offers a complete USB host stack.

Based on a few previous questions it seems like for a start you should be looking for a Linux SBC (single-board computer) that will handle the USB host side of things and also provide a convenient software stack to interface with the barcode scanner, camera and mass-storage devices.

Maybe take a look at something like a OLinuXino series, BeagleBone, Raspberry Pi etc or whatever Linux SBC gives the interfaces you need for a start. If the project idea takes off then you can take a look at some custom hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance! I understand much better now. Appreciate your suggestions too! @PeterJ